# Use python 2 module in python 3 in mac OS

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

I would like to use installed Python 2 modules in Python 3.

One step would be to add to the PythonPath3 the directories where the Python2 modules are installed. Of course this would work only if the modules are coded for Python3 compatibility.

Is there a way that I can import modules in Python3 and have them automatically converted (using 2to3) to usable Python3 code?

Specs: Mac OS 10.9.1
Python2 = python 2.7.6
Python3 = python 3.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no, you can't do that easily.  Just bite the bullet and install new copies of the modules you need for your Python 3 installation.  Remember to first install a new copy of `pip` (or, if you must, `easy_install`) using your Python 3.3 and use it to install the modules you need for Python 3.

One of the reasons you can't is that for many packages that support both Python 2 and 3 by using 2to3 require the source distribution to do so.  The resultant Python 2 installed distribution will not necessarily have everything needed to produce a new Python 3 installation.